# Writing to Database when executing controller's index method - error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I call the `index()` method of the collaborating controller, it automatically inserts 6 records into the database, and the action of logging into the database is not in the `cadastrarquestao()` method of the class, and not in the index method . I'm using a template library.

Controller Colaborador:

```
<?php
```

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Colaborador extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('funcoes_helper');
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('cookie');          
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('controle_acesso');
    $this->load->model('resumoapp_model', 'resumo');
    $this->load->model('homeapp_model', 'homeapp');
    $this->load->model('simulado_model', 'simulado');


    
    $this->controle_acesso->acesso();

    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    
}

public function index() {


    $dados['teste'] = 1;        
    
    $this->template->load("template/template_app",'app/enviar-questao', $dados);

}   

public function logout()    { 

    session_unset();

    redirect ('/entrar');

}

public function cadastrarquestao()  {       

    $this->simulado->envioquestao(1);

    $dados['mensagem'] = "dados cadastrados com sucesso!";
    $this->template->load("template/template_app",'app/enviar-questao', $dados);

}

public function materia()   { 

    
}
```

}

part of the code

```
public function envioquestao($dados) {          
        $data = [
            'Id_usuario' => $this->session->userdata('id_usuario'),             
        ];

        $this->db->insert('teste',$data);
}
```

librarie Template:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Template {
        var $template_data = array();
        
        function set($name, $value)
        {
            $this->template_data[$name] = $value;
        }
    
        function load($template = '', $view = '' , $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
        {               
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->set('contents', $this->CI->load->view($view, $view_data, TRUE));         
            return $this->CI->load->view($template, $this->template_data, $return);
        }
}
```

View template:

```
<html lang="pt-br">

<?php   
  $this->load->view('app/header');
?>

<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <?php
         $this->load->view('app/topo');
      ?>
      
      <?php 
         $this->load->view('app/menu');
      ?>
      
      
         <?php echo $contents ?>
   
      <footer class="footer-container"><span>&copy; </span></footer>
   </div>
   <?php
      $this->load->view('app/footer');
   ?>
</body>

</html>
```

the correct one would be to insert it in the database after clicking on 'register' which is in the `cadastrarquestao()` method

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you're trying to figure out why it's inserting into the database while there seems to be no code that does the inserting, try commenting out all of the lines in the constructor (and maybe also comment out all of the other methods besides `index`) and then add them back in one by one to see if any of those do the database insertion.

Comment: @Marleen what you said, I don't know why the insertion is done without the method invoked to do the insertion.
I'll make your suggestion, but the structure is relatively simple and I can't identify the problem!
Another thing that happens, when I call the method to insert the database, instead of inserting a line, 8, 15 lines are inserted. without explanation this error